# Resolving NED Path issue Veins/Omnet++

Tags: simulation, omnet++, veins

I am working with veins. I needed to change the default behavior of `BaseWaveApplLayer`. Rather doing in file changes, I created a second application file with the name `MyApp`. I added `MyApp.cc`, `MyApp.h`, `MyApp.ned` files. Then I duplicated `TraCIDemoRSU11p`, and added files for `TraCIDemoRSU11pEnhanced`. Now in `.ini` file when I changed `*.rsu[*].applType` to point to "TraCIDemoRSU11pEnhanced". It compiles fine, but when I try to run it, generates the following error:

```
 Submodule appl: no module type named `TraCIDemo11pEnhanced' found that implements module interface org.car2x.veins.base.modules.IBaseApplLayer (not in the loaded NED files?).
```

In `MyApp.ned` file it is declared to be of type `IBaseApplLayer`. I tried setting `ned-path` parameter in ini file, didn't resolve the problem. In veins project properties, NED source folder is checked. Do I have to add the ned path for the newly created application file, somewhere?

Comment: Check that the NED path is set correctly -- the output just before the error you pasted should tell you where OMNeT++ thinks the NED files should be. Also make sure that the `.ned` file contains the correct path and name within the file (did you rename the module to TraCIDemoRSU11pEnhanced?).

Comment: @RensvanderHeijden I did check it. It says something `Loading NED files from .: 1
Loading NED files from ../../src/veins: 32
Loading NED files from /home/path/veins-4a2/examples/veins: 1` . The files are at /src/veins. Actually `TraCIDemoRSU11pEnhanced` is in the same folder as `TraCIDemoRSU11p`. I double checked it, the name checks out. I didn't rename the original module, I created another file under this name that extends `MyApp`.

Comment: What is the exact name of duplicated NED module that you have prepared: **`TraCIDemoRSU11pEnhanced`** or **`TraCIDemo11pEnhanced`**? Because you have mentioned `TraCIDemoRSU11pEnhanced` but in the error is `TraCIDemo11pEnhanced`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the cookiecutter package (https://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/#newprojects) to create new applications that use veins instead of copying and pasting files:
Use pip to install the package (https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter)
Then follow the steps in (https://github.com/veins/cookiecutter-veins-project/blob/master/README.md) to create the new project; following the prompts that appear.
This will create a new project that uses Veins and has the application layer-related files for you to update according to your application with no errors.